# Simple 2d physics tutorial for terrain collision detection

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics

I am looking for a tutorial which will show me how to do simple 2d physics like the ones in [this](http://www.teagames.com/games/tgmotocross/play.php) (http://www.teagames.com/games/tgmotocross/play.php).  The part that I am most interested in is how the collision detection is done between the character / player and the terrain, as well as how to store / generate the terrain.
The language of the tutorial doesn't matter - I am just interested in how to do this in general.
Many thanks.

---

**EDIT**: To clarify, I already know how to perform collision detection between two sprites, and enough physics to write a 2d game - I am looking specifically for a tutorial / example on how to implement the smooth terrain which can be collided with (I understand how destroyable landscapes are done, and I presume that this would be related somehow). Also, I am aware of the N tutorials but that uses discrete shapes whereas I am interested in a smooth landscape.

Comment: Head over to gamedev.net there are loads of tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you take a look at the [Farseer Physics Engine](http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics) which is a 2d engine for .NET written in C#.  You can look [here](http://www.farseergames.com/) for some examples of this package in use.  Very easy to use and understand.  A great place to get started understanding such things.  Also, the people making the product are very easy to get ahold of and chat with if you have questions!

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest them but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 3):

I have found that [this](http://jnrdev.72dpiarmy.com/en/jnrdev5/) link is somewhat helpful (mostly for a worms type game) - at the bottom it says that if you want to find the normal at the collision point (which would probably be needed to orientate a vehicle correctly) you have to scan the area around the collision point and create a plane for further maths.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you already:

1. understand Vectors
2. understand Physics

Take a look at [this](http://books.google.gr/books?id=lRUj-nhQRu8C&pg=PA836&lpg=PA836&dq=game+programming+vectors+physics&source=bl&ots=7vD94EI8-x&sig=X8DEWfrx7602Ijw83tXbtVbCvPk&hl=el&ei=6DwzSpyTHYKD_Ab9n42fCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2#PPA817,M1).

Comment: If only I spoke Greek, and if I was in Greece then I could view this book!